# Modify Field In On Instance In LiveCycle

Tags: javascript, livecycle

I'm working in LiveCycle creating a form that allows the user to duplicate a sub form as they need. In that set of fields there is a dropdown and if it is set to certain values a field that is normally hidden should display. I only want this to display in that instance of the sub form that they made that selection. So my question is how do I determine which instance fired off the event? If I get that I think I can go from there with making the change.

I'm still new to LiveCycle and the resources out there are scattered at best. Any help is appreciated.

PS I'm using Javascript and not FormCalc.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use built-in functionality that helps you to address proper objects in your code. When you are typing your code in the script window, just hold Ctrl and mouse click the object you want to refer your code to. It will generate a correct short version DOM name for that object. If you hold Ctrl-Shift and then click, you'll get a full DOM address for that object.

For example, you have a 1-page form that has a subform, which can get multiple instances. Inside that subform you have a drop-down "Selector" which controls visibility of the text field called "Weight". Your DOM addresses will look like follows

form1.page1.subform.Selector - this is your drop-down
form1.page1.subform.Weight - this is your text field

Now because your script is located inside of the object in the same subform that has also the object you want to control, you don't even need to pay attention of any instance numbers.

In your script window of form1.page1.subform.Selector just type

```
if (this.rawValue == "Yes"){
Weight.presence = "visible";
}
```

It will address only the object that is located in the same subform with your drop-down controller.